# ogr2ogr expose osm_id in GeoJSON?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, ogr2ogr

I am converting osm xml to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr and I want to use the `osm_id`, nested under `properties`, as a top level `id` field.

Running

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson input.osm points`

produces something like the following, where the `osm_id` is nested within the `properties`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "points",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "osm_id": "32927591",
        "other_tags": "\"noref\"=>\"yes\"",
        "highway": "motorway_junction"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -122.4254065,
          37.7313829
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I would like to generate a the Geojson using the `osm_id` as a top level `id` attribute:

```
  "features": [
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "32927591",
      "properties": {
        "osm_id": "32927591",
        "other_tags": "\"noref\"=>\"yes\"",
        "highway": "motorway_junction"
      },
      "geometry": {...
```

Is there a way to do this with `ogr2ogr`? Is there a different tool you'd recommend?

Comment: Solution, for my version of GDAL, was to use the `preserve_fid` flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case osm_id is a fid field already in the source data and you can simply run ogr2ogr with the `-preserve_fid` option http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html.

With GDAL version 2.3 or higher it is also possible to select the field that will be used as id in GeoJSON by using the GeoJSON driver specific layer creation option `-lco id_field=` http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html. Just take care to select a field that is unique in the source data because duplicate fids will make trouble later.

Your command with the latter approach would be

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -lco id_field=osm_id output.geojson input.osm points
```

Test with a small self-made dataset:

```
ogr2ogr -f geojson -lco id_field=osm_id osm_id_test.json osm_id_test.jml
```

Result:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "osm_id_test",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 383.0, 458.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 440.0, 381.0 ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have 2.2.4. But I just figured out that I can use the `preserve_fid` flag to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: I edited my answer so that -preserve_fid is the primary option and id_field an alternative for that.